# Delete node from the end of the linked list for the given index

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error

I'm trying to solve LeetCode problem [19. Remove Nth Node From End of List](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-nth-node-from-end-of-list/)
:

> Given the `head` of a linked list, remove the `n`<sup>th</sup> node from the end of the list and return its head.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> [image]
>
> **Input:** `head = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `n = 2`
>
> **Output:** `[1,2,3,5]`

This is the code I wrote:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        while (head->next!=NULL){
            head = head -> next ;
            count++;
        }
        int len;
        len = count - n ;
        ListNode* curr = head; 
        for(int i =len ; i > 0 ; i--){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = curr->next->next;
        return head;

    }
};
```

I get this error:

> Line 23: Char 26: runtime error: member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode' (solution.cpp)
>
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:32:26

Can someone tell what is wrong in the code, that it raises this error?

Comment: Don't use `NULL` in modern C++. Always use [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- The first loop makes `head` reference the last node in the list. But that means your second loop will start from *there*, not from the first node of the list. And so in the first iteration of the second loop, `curr = curr->next` will assign `nullptr` to `curr`, and its second iteration will run into the error you saw. You should not use `head` as a tool to traverse the list. Use a separate variable for that.
- The similar error will occur when the node to remove is the last node in the list. In that case the expression `curr->next->next` will raise the error. `curr->next` is null in that case. You should deal with this boundary case and first verify whether `curr->next` is null and act accordingly.
- Your code does not foresee the case where the first node needs to be removed, which means you have to return the successor of `head`.

(Not a problem, but `NULL` should not be used in C++ code, use `nullptr`).

Here is your code with the corrections needed to fix these three issues:

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode* curr = head; // Use a different variable for the traversal
        while (curr->next) { // Don't use NULL
            curr = curr -> next ;
            count++;
        }
        int len;
        len = count - n;
        if (len < 0) { // Deal with removal of first node
            return head->next;
        }
        curr = head; 
        for (int i = len ; i > 0 ; i--) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        // Deal with removal of last node (when curr->next is nullptr)
        curr->next = curr->next ? curr->next->next : nullptr;
        return head;
    }
};
```